# Is NSNumber overkill for an instance-level counter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber, nsinteger

I'm new to Objective-C and Cocoa.  I've read that NSInteger and NSNumber are preferred when working with simple integers because they're the "platform-safe" versions of the primitive numeric types (and in NSNumber's case, wrapped in an object).  So, I need a counter in my class that gets incremented when an NSTimer fires.  On an Apple forum I found a group of people all recommending to someone in a similar situation that they should declare a NSNumber pointer in the header, initialize it with numberWithInt:, and then each time it needs to be incremented do so by assigning it to a new object (something like `counter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[counter intValue]+1];`).  This looks like overkill to me.  If all I need is an int counter (and btw, I'm resetting it back to 0 after it hits 15 so size isn't an issue), can't I get away with just using an int and not have to allocate a new object with each iteration of my timer's loop?

And if so, how do I make a primitive type available throughout my class.  I know that with object types, I declare it in my interface and use @property and @synthesize...what's the equivalent (if one exists) when working with primitives?

Comment: To your second question: It's the same, just use @property and @synthesize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using NSNumber for a simple counter does look a little bit of over kill. You can declare class members as NSInteger and simply update them using ++ or +=

for example:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController  {
NSInteger counter;      
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger counter;
```

The @synthesize is just:

```
@synthesize counter
```

and can be incremented either by:

```
self.counter += 1;
```

or

```
counter ++;
```

the later will prevent any observers from being informed, thus might not be preferable.

Answer (score 9):

NSNumber is an object representation of a number. I use it when storing numbers in a collection class because they can only hold object pointers.

So in your example, which needs a counter, it probably is overkill.

NSInteger is simply an integer that is typedefed to be safe for 32 and 64 bit programs, and is recommended by Apple for use instead of `int`. It is not an object. This is probably what you need for a counter (actually NSUInteger, which is an `unsigned int`) might be better.

As for making primitives available throughout your class - well, if you declare it in the header as an iVar, it is available throughout your class anyway. `@property` and `@synthesize` are just Objective-C 2.0 ways of declaring these as properties that can be seen (and perhaps changed) outside of your class in a KVC/KVO compliant manner. Primitive types can be used as properties using the same `@property` and `@synthesize` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I use `NSInteger` (not int, to be more portable), and wrap it into a `NSNumber` if I need to add it to a collection (such as a `NSMutableDictionary` when saving the state on quitting the application).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your instinct, using an object for a simple counter sounds like overkill and will add an unnecessary number of message dispatch calls for simply incrementing a counter.  For a counter that doesn't need to be stored in a collection or manipulated as an object, stick with C scalar types.

To declare a scalar as an instance variable of your class, just declare it in your header file:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject{
  int counter;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* need to increment an NSNumber (such as for an NSManagedObject property) I found this category helped:

```
@interface NSNumber (Incrementer)
- (NSNumber *)increment;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (Incrementer)
- (NSNumber *)increment {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self intValue]+1];
}
@end
```

so you can simplify the increment statements to:

```
counter = [counter increment];
```